# Python using open (w+) FileNotFoundError

Tags: python

I get a `FileNotFoundError` when trying to write to a file.
This is my code:

```
def save_txt_individual_tracks(track, folder, i):
    f = open(folder+str(i)+'.txt','w+')
        for line in track:
            l=str(line[0])+','+str(line[1])+','+str(line[2])+'\n'
        f.write(l)
    f.close()
```

Which I call like so:

```
save_txt_individual_tracks(new,'E:/phoneTracks/'+track_name+'/',i)
```

Which gives me this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/phoneTracks/TA92903URN7ff/0.txt'

I created folder `phoneTracks` in E. And I am confused about `open()` with mode `'w+'`, which is used to create a new file. Why do I get a `FileNotFoundError`? What can I do to fix it?

I am running python3.4.3 on windows 7

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you @poke for your help. And I will read these useful tips listed by Morgan Thrapp.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are getting the error because the directory - `E:/phoneTracks/TA92903URN7ff/` does not exist.

Example to show this error -

```
In [57]: open('blah/abcd.txt','w+')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-46a07d4a5d18> in <module>()
----> 1 open('blah/abcd.txt','w+')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'blah/abcd.txt'
```

Got error in my code, because the directory `blah/` does not exist.

If the directory - `TA92903URN7ff/` is constant, try creating it and then running. If its not constant, you can checkout [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to check if the directory exists or not, and if it doesn't exist, create one using [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) .

Example -

```
import os, os.path
def save_txt_individual_tracks(track,folder,i):
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
         os.mkdir(folder)
    elif not os.path.isdir(folder):
         return #you may want to throw some error or so.
    f = open(os.path.join(folder, str(i)+'.txt'),'w+')
        for line in track:
            l=str(line[0])+','+str(line[1])+','+str(line[2])+'\n'
        f.write(l)
    f.close()
```

Also, you should consider using `os.path.join` to join paths, instead of using string concatenation. And also using `with` statement for openning files as - `with open(os.path.join(folder, str(i)+'.txt'),'w+') as f:` , that way the file will automatically get closed once the `with` block ends.

Comment: Thank you very much @Anand S Kumar. The directory- 'TA92903URN7ff' is constant. I fixed the problem after using 'os.path.join'. By the way, I change 'foldermstr(i)' to 'folder+str(i)'.